# Динамическое создание SVG фигур?

Tags: css3, svg, анимация, css-animation

Есть ли такая возможность без привлечения `JS` динамически, с какой-то периодичностью создавать (или менять) размеры `SVG` фигур. Например,- треугольника?

```html
<svg width="230" height="140">
    <polygon points="5,135 115,5 225,135"
             fill="violet" stroke="purple" stroke-width="5" />
</svg>
```

Как каждую секунду менять случайным образом размер этой фигуры ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Треугольники каждую секунду дискретно меняют свои координаты всех вершин и цвет. 
Комбинация = форма треугольника + цвет = уникальна, на протяжении одной анимации. 
Если цвет менять не надо, то можно просто полностью убрать строчку :

`<animate attributeName="fill" values="pink;greenyellow;skyblue;violet;orangered;yellowgreen;gold;teal" dur="8s" calcMode="discrete"   repeatCount="indefinite" fill="freeze" />`

```html
<svg width="230" height="230">
    <polygon points="5,135 115,5 225,135"
             fill="violet" stroke="purple" stroke-width="2" >
   <animate attributeName="points" values="5,135 115,45 225,135;105,135 115,5 225,115;10,135 115,5 115,115;10,35 110,35 55,115;10,35 110,35 110,115;10,115 140,115 140,15;10,15 220,70 10,140;20,30 50,10 150,150;10,100 180,10 160,200;50,150 75,20 100,150;50,50 60,10 150,150;20,20 100,50 20,100;20,20 180,20 195,70; 30,150 100,20 150,65;20,20 70,70 50,150 " dur="15s" calcMode="discrete"   repeatCount="indefinite" fill="freeze" />
   <animate attributeName="fill" values="pink;greenyellow;skyblue;violet;orangered;yellowgreen;gold;teal" dur="8s" calcMode="discrete"   repeatCount="indefinite" fill="freeze" />
  </polygon>   
</svg>
```

Comment: я задания не поняла, мой ответ тут совсем не по теме

Comment: Можно создать новый вопрос с самоответом. Если код хорош, то нет ничего плохого в том, чтобы отдельно запостить.